# Can't get Visual Studio's "Publish Web Application" to work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, one-click-web-publishing

I converted a small Web Project to a Web Application in Visual Studio 2010.

When I publish the application via FTP it will delete everything at the destination. And thats it...none of my files get uploaded.

Now, If I select "Replace matching files with local copies" it uploads all my files but it does run my Pre/Post Build commands but never uploads the resulting files (the Build Events create .min.js versions of my JS files).

I figure that whatever I'm doing...I'm doing it wrong.

Help me please.

---

**UPDATE**

So, the .min.js versions of my JS files weren't actually in the project. They were created successfully on each build...but they didn't show up in the Solution Explorer. So, I put them there and now it works okay.

Now my problem is that I don't want to see my Release build's .min.js files in Solution Explorer...ever. Do I just have to deal with it or is there something I am missing?

Comment: "FTP" adds the interesting wrinkle there.

Comment: GoDaddy.com hosting. And it worked fine when it was a Web Project (obviously no Build Events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was to "Add > Existing Item" to the project to include the minified versions of my scripts in the project.

As for the other question: "ow my problem is that I don't want to see my Release build's .min.js files in Solution Explorer...ever. Do I just have to deal with it or is there something I am missing?"

I'm going to go with "I just have to deal with it" as the answer.